# running server error for develop Django on Openshift

Tags: python, django, openshift

I am newbie to Django and Openshift. I highly hope to learn Django on the openshift. but I got some problem on setup. I am success to access the file on the server. but I am failed to create a hello world page even I try many different syntax and test many time.

The only thing I can do is to creat user and access the admin layout on
http://dj-kkhchan.rhcloud.com/admin

The following is my step for creating hello world page.

1. use startapp to create a app(named card)
2. add the app to myproject/settings.py

   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'card',
3. edit the views(card\views.py) as

   `from django.http import HttpResponse
   def hello_world(request):
       return HttpResponse("Hello World!")`
4. edit the myproject/urls.py like this

   ```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/$', views.hellow_word),
    ]
   ```

When I browse http://dj-kkhchan.rhcloud.com/hello/

It show "file not found".

Supplement: the python version is 3.3 and Django is 1.8.4

In fact, I tried pythonAnywhere.com and success to create hello world on this site. so I wonder why I can't setup it on Openshift well.

Comment: runserver is not for production. There is no reason you should be running it on your server.